# Check if cell contains certain text and write text in other workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Here is one cell `CVSS2#AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:P/A:P` I would like to iterate over it and, as an example:

```
if cell contains AV:N then
    write in another workbook Network(N)
else if cell contains AV:A then
    write in another workbook Adjacent(A)
```

This should check all possibilities and should be done in a certain range of columns.

Thank you all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given us very little information as to where your range resides and which workbook you would like to write to and its range, but I will attempt to give you a way of doing what you are trying to achieve:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
Dim IsOpen As Boolean

IsOpen = IsWorkBookOpen("C:\Network(N).xlsx") 'check if workbook is open
If Not IsOpen Then
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Network(N).xlsx") 'if not already open, then open it
End If

Dim wbNet As Workbook: Set wbNet = Workbook("C:\Network(N).xlsx")
Dim wsNet As Worksheet: Set wsNet = wbNet.Sheets("Sheet1")

IsOpen = IsWorkBookOpen("C:\Adjacent(A).xlsx") 'check if workbook is open
If Not IsOpen Then
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Adjacent(A).xlsx") 'if not already open, then open it
End If

Dim wbAdj As Workbook: Set wbAdj = Workbook("C:\Adjacent(A).xlsx")
Dim wsAdj As Worksheet: Set wsAdj = wbAdj.Sheets("Sheet1")

For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to last on your worksheet in Column A
    If InStr(ws.Cells(i, 1), "AV:N") > 0 Then 'if "AV:N" found then
        NetworkLast = wsNet.Cells(wsNet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'find the next free row on this worksheet
        wsNet.Cells(NetworkLast, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1) 'pass the contents of your cell to that worksheet
    ElseIf InStr(ws.Cells(i, 1), "AV:A") > 0 Then
        AdjacentLast = wsAdj.Cells(wsNet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wsAdj.Cells(AdjacentLast, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1)
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(Name As String) As Boolean
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWb = Application.Workbooks.Item(Name)
    IsWorkBookOpen = (Not xWb Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: Hello Xabier, thank you for your answer, I think this will work for me.